# EF code first обновления "nullable" поле

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

У меня есть две связанные таблицы:

```
public class InspectionItems
{
    [Key]
    public int InspectionItemID { get; set; }
    .........
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string QualiteGradeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QualiteGradeID")]
    public virtual QualityGrades QualityGrades { get; set; }
}

 public partial class QualityGrades
 {
    [Key]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string QualiteGradeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

    InspectionItems inspectionItem = _unitOfWork.InspectionItems.All().FirstOrDefault(it          => it.InspectionItemID == item.Id);
            if (inspectionItem != null)
            {
                inspectionItem.QualiteGradeID = "RR";

               _unitOfWork.InspectionItems.Update(inspectionItem);
                _unitOfWork.Commit();
            }

    public override void Update(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot update a null entity.");
        }

        _dbSet.Local.Clear();
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Мне нужно обновить поле QualiteGradeID таблицы InspectionItems, проблема заключается в том, что в базе данных **это поле может имеет тип NULL**, и когда я пытаюсь его обновить, у меня генерируется SQL:

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[InspectionItems]
 SET [QualiteGradeID] = NULL
 WHERE ([InspectionItemID] = @1)
```

Делаю эксперимент: запрещаю NULL значения в поле QualiteGradeID(таблицы InspectionItems) - и все начинает работать. Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным поведением, буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: @Vladimirr, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

ID вы не можете установить, потому что в Local не загружены QualityGrades. Либо устанавливайте навигацинное самостоятельно, либо добавьте к запросу выбора inspectionItem Include c QualityGrades.

Вы используете UnitOfWork, чтоб DI использовать для тестов?

Если нет, то рекомендую Вам отказаться от UnitOfWork и всяческих репозиториев. По ссылке есть ответ, в котором человек объясняет, что это все от лукавого)))

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47879/unit-of-work-and-repository-with-entity-framework-6

P.S. А зачем вы Local очищаете, а потом приатачиваете объект?

Comment: убрал _dbSet.Local.Clear();  _dbSet.Attach(entity); из функций Update() и все заработало. Наверно вы правы когда вызываю Local.Clear() теряется связь  с таблицой QualityGrades, и так как обновляемое поле имеет связь FK c таблицой QualityGrades, EF не понимает правильное значение он в таблицу вставляет или нет.